# How to install new version of ubuntu and keep home partition untouched

Tags: system-installation

My PC is ubuntu 14.

My PC contains 2 partitions: "/" and "/home"

I do not want to backup the data in another disk. I want to keep it when installing new version

how to install new version of ubuntu 16 and keep the "/home" untouched and keep the same user

Comment: @Graham I don't think it's a dupe of that one since /home is already in other partition.

Comment: Why install version 16 when the current LTS version is 18.04?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To install a new version while maintaining your current separate /home partition, you need to select "Something else" between the options that the installer presents.

[image]

That brings you to a screen where you can designate mount points for the new installation yourself.

[image]

In that screen, assign your current root partition (`/`) to become the root partition of the new installation. To that aim, you click the partition. You then get an "Edit partition" dialog:

[image]

There you indicate how the partition must be formatted ("use as"), whether the partition must be formatted or not, and where the partition must be mounted.

- **For the partition you currently use as root partition**: Use as: ext4; Format: Yes; Mount point: `/`.
- **For the partition you currently use as home partition**: Use as: ext4 (provided it is currently in ext4); Format: **No**; Mount point: `/home`.

If you continue the installation, the root partition will be fully wiped. The files on the '/home' partition will be preserved.

Comment: I voted to reopen this question because I'd like to use it as the canonical question for duplicate questions of this type from now on,